# What deserializes GWT RPC calls client side

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, deserialization, rpc

As far as I have understood it is the RemoteServiceServlet that deserializes and serializes incoming and outgoing data on the server side in my GWT project.

But what about client-side? My serviceAsync class, which I suppose receives the response from the RemoteServiceServlet, does not extend anything.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the section about RPC plumbing (the green box in the diagram) :

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html

> Some of these classes, such as the service proxy, are automatically generated behind the scenes and you generally will never realize they exist.

Comment: so it is the service proxy class created with ".. = GWT.create(YourService.class)" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the deserialisation util code for java types in GWT User Code (gwt-user.jar ) under package com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core

https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/tree/46173a7c2511d1156d56fd564717fe6f7cf4a97e/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/core/java

Example - com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.lang

```
Boolean_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Byte_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Character_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Double_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Float_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Integer_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Long_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Object_Array_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Short_CustomFieldSerializer.java
StackTraceElement_CustomFieldSerializer.java
String_CustomFieldSerializer.java
Void_CustomFieldSerializer.java
```

For Custom Code which extends GWT IsSerializable or Serializable GWT generates similar FieldSerializer classes during compilation.

Comment: so these classes handle the serialization and deserialization of data send from client-side to server-side over the network and NOT the service proxy class?

Answer (score 0):

This is taken care of by GWT. All you need to make sure is your DTOs are serializable.